# Suma total de una columna a traves de un data griedview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

¿Cómo hago una suma total de una columna a través de un data *griedview* en **c#**
si mis valores están enlazados a una tabla de *mysql workbench*
y mi suma total la quiero mostrar en un *label*?

Answer (score 0):

para poderte ayudar debes mostrar el código que tienes.

Podrás hacer la suma usando linq

```
var suma =  GridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Sum(x=> Convert.ToDecimal(x.Row.Cells[1].Text));

lblsuma.Text = Convert.ToString(suma);
```

Answer (score 0):

también podrías usar el ItemSource del DataGrid, algo asi:

```
var suma = ItemSource.Sum(x=> x.ValorASumarEntero);
```

Es solo un ejemplo, espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione asi:

```
  int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
        }
        label7.Text = sum.ToString();
```